# Group duplicate mysql results under a same result

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql

I'm working on a chat system with an existing DB structure that I can't modify.

I'm trying to fetch messages that were received while being offline for a particular user (let's say the user is me).

Currently, my query gives me results such as:

```
[ { username: 'Chico',
    message: 'chicoMessage1',
    sentBy: 23 },
  { username: 'rep',
    message: 'repMessage1',
    sentBy: 59 },
  { username: 'Chico',
    message: 'chicoMessage2',
    sentBy: 23 },
  { username: 'rep',
    message: 'repMessage2',
    sentBy: 59 } ]
```

The above results mean that the user "Chico" sent me 2 messages, and user "rep" sent me 2 as well. We see the content of the message, and the ID's of the message senders.

The end results I'd like to get, so I can efficiently work with it, would be to have the content above for each username, to be grouped under the same username .

So basically something like that would be good:

```
[ { username: 'Chico',
    messages: ['chicoMessage1', 'chicoMessage1' ],
    sentBy: 23 },
  { username: 'rep',
    messages: ['repMessage1', 'repMessage2' ],
    sentBy: 59 } ]
```

Could I do that with MySQL? Here's the query I have now (that results in the results mentioned earlier):

```
  SELECT tusers.username, messages.message, messages.sentBy
  FROM messages
  JOIN offlineconversations
  ON messages.messageID = offlineconversations.messageID
  JOIN tusers
  ON tusers.id = messages.sentBy \
  WHERE offlineconversations.userID = 100;
```

The tables look like:

**tusers**

id | username | password

**messages**

messageID | message | sentBy

**offlineconversations**

userID | messageID

Could MySQL achieve what I want? If not, how would you do it (in JS)?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use GROUP_CONCAT function and GROUP BY clause:
 https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

```
SELECT tusers.username, messages.sentBy, 
       GROUP_CONCAT( messages.message ) As messages 
  FROM messages
  JOIN offlineconversations
  ON messages.messageID = offlineconversations.messageID
  JOIN tusers
  ON tusers.id = messages.sentBy 
  WHERE offlineconversations.userID = 100
GROUP BY tusers.username, messages.sentBy;
```

Comment: I also have a 'createdAt' timestamp column in the `messages` table, how could I use it to order the messages from newest to oldest?

Comment: Use `GROUP_CONCAT(messages.message ORDER BY createdAt DESC )`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I added SEPARATOR '-_-_-' then I split the string via JS with that separator to create an array of the messages. Is there a more optimal way to get that array straight out of MySQL? Thanks

Comment: If this query is slow, try to optimize it using indexes. First run `explain extended` command on the query and save it's results for further comparisons. Then try to create indexes on `messageId` (if it is not a primary key already), on `createdAt`, also multicolumn index on `messageId + createdAt` is worth to give it a try. Run explain again after creating each index and compare results, also test the sped of query after each step. You can also ask a new question on SO concerning the optimization of this query.